# Natural Pi #0 - Rock

Tags: code-golf, math, random, pi, approximation

### Goal

Create a program/function that takes an input `N`, check if `N` random pairs of integers are relatively prime, and returns `sqrt(6 * N / #coprime)`.

### TL;DR

These challenges are simulations of algorithms that only require nature and your brain (and maybe some re-usable resources) to approximate Pi. If you really need Pi during the zombie apocalypse, these methods don't [waste ammo](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/how-mathematicians-used-a-pump-action-shotgun-to-estimate-pi-c1eb776193ef#.eld2u7w76)! There are eight more challenges to come. Checkout the [sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10035/43214) to make recommendations.

### Simulation

**What are we simulating?** Well, the probability that two random integers are relatively prime (ie coprime or gcd==1) is [`6/Pi/Pi`](https://mathoverflow.net/a/97045), so a natural way to calculate Pi would be to scoop up two buckets (or handfuls) of rocks; count them; see if their [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) is 1; repeat. After doing this a <s>couple</s> lot of times, `sqrt(6.0 * total / num_coprimes)` will tend towards `Pi`. If calculating the square-root in post-apocalyptic world makes you nervous, don't worry! There is [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number) for that.

**How are we simulating this?**

- Take input `N`
- Do the following `N` times:

  - Uniformly generate random positive integers, `i` and `j`
  - With `1 <= i , j <= 10^6`
  - If `gcd(i , j) == 1`: `result = 1`
  - Else: `result = 0`
- Take the sum of the `N` results, `S`
- Return `sqrt(6 * N / S)`

[image]

### Specification

- **Input**

  - Flexible, take input in any of the standard ways (eg function parameter,STDIN) and in any standard format (eg String, Binary)
- **Output**

  - Flexible, give output in any of the standard ways (eg return, print)
  - White space, trailing and leading white space is acceptable
  - Accuracy, please provide at least 4 decimal places of accuracy (ie `3.1416`)
- **Scoring**

  - Shortest code wins!

### Test Cases

Your output may not line up with these, because of random chance. But on average, you should get about this much accuracy for the given value of `N`.

```
Input     ->  Output 
-----         ------
100       ->  3.????
10000     ->  3.1???
1000000   ->  3.14??
```

Comment: Does our answer need to work for `N = 1000000` or is it ok if the program returns e.g. a stack overflow if `N` is too big?

Comment: @Fatalize if it is a limitation of the language, sure. Otherwise, you need to handle `N=10^6`.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67773/co-primality-and-the-number-pi)

Comment: The goal is misleading, it states only one pair of integers is checked.

Comment: @immibis I meant the goal to be a short overview with exact details in the specification. I thought the `#coprime` might indicate multiple pairs.

Comment: Does the upper limit to the random numbers generated need to be exactly 1000000? Would a larger upper limit be acceptable?

Comment: @Sok A larger upper limit is acceptable

Comment: I agree with @immibis, something like "check if `N` random pairs of integers are relatively prime" might be clearer.

Answer (score 12):

## APL, 23 bytes

```
{.5*⍨6×⍵÷1+.=∨/?⍵2⍴1e6}
```

Explanation:

- `?⍵2⍴1e6`: generate a 2-by-⍵ matrix of random numbers in the range [1..10<sup>6</sup>]
- `1+.=∨/`: get the GCD of each pair and see how many are equal to 1. This calculates S.
- `.5*⍨6×⍵÷`: (6 × ⍵ ÷ S)<sup>0.5</sup>

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20 18</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes thanks to @Pietu1998 (chain & use count 1s, `ċ1` in place of less than two summed `<2S`)

-2 bytes thanks to @Dennis (repeat 1e6 multiple times before sampling to avoid chaining)

```
Ḥȷ6xX€g2/ċ1÷³6÷½
```

(Extremely slow due to the random function)

How?

```
Ḥȷ6xX€g2/ċ1÷³6÷½ - Main link: n
 ȷ6              - 1e6
   x             - repeat
Ḥ                -     double, 2n
    X€           - random integer in [1,1e6] for each
       2/        - pairwise reduce with
      g          -     gcd
         ċ1      - count 1s
           ÷     - divide
            ³    - first input, n
             6   - literal 6
              ÷  - divide
               ½ - square root
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/)**

Comment: `ḤRµȷ6Xµ€g2/ċ1÷³6÷½` saves 2 bytes. (`ȷ6` is 10^6 in a single nilad, `ċ1` counts ones)

Comment: Ah I couldn't work out how to chain it up like that (I tried a few things), and forgot the count 1 trick - thanks (I think `ȷ²` is a tiny tiny bit faster than `ȷ6`)

Comment: Might be. Now that I think of it, `ȷ²` being two links doesn't hurt here, but would require an extra link or `¤` for some use cases

Comment: `Ḥȷ6xX€` should work for the random sampling.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, <s>143</s> <s>140</s> <s>132</s> <s>124</s> <s>122</s> <s>124</s> [122 bytes](https://goo.gl/7RS871)

It has been quite some time since I have tried golfing, so I may have missed something here! Will be updating as I shorten this.

```py
import random as r,fractions as f
n,s=input(),0
k=lambda:r.randrange(1e6)+1
exec's+=f.gcd(k(),k())<2;'*n
print(6.*n/s)**.5
```

<sup>Test me [here!](https://repl.it/DnAQ/2)</sup>

<sup>*thanks to Jonathan Allan for the two-byte save :)*</sup>

Comment: According to OP, `1 <= i , j <= 10^6`, so you need to use `randrange(1,1e6+1)`.

Comment: Also, it's really strange to have the repl.it link within the language name. A link in the lang name should be to the language's home page, if anything. Put your repl.it link as a separate link below your code.

Comment: @mbomb007 Good point, I've fixed it :) Been a while!

Comment: `k=lambda:r.randrange(1e6)+1` saves two bytes

Comment: @JonathanAllan good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 51 bytes

Saved one byte and fixed one bug thanks to [@LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/33208/legionmammal978).

```
(6#/Count[GCD@@{1,1*^6}~RandomInteger~{2,#},1])^.5&
```

Comment: You can save a byte: `(6#/Count[GCD@@1*^6~RandomInteger~{2,#},1])^.5&`

Comment: Also, `1*^6` should be replaced with `{1,1*^6}` to ensure that *i*, *j* ≠ 0.

Answer (score 8):

## R, <s>103</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s> 94 bytes

Can likely be golfed down a bit. Cut down 4 bytes due to @antoine-sac, and another 4 bytes by defining an alias for `sample`, using `^.5` instead of `sqrt`, and `1e6` instead of `10^6`. Added 4 bytes to ensure that the sampling of `i` and `j` is truly uniform. Removed one byte after I realized that `6*N/sum(x)` is the same as `6/mean(x)`. Used `pryr::f` instead of `function(x,y)` to save 4 bytes.

```
N=scan()
s=sample
g=pryr::f(ifelse(o<-x%%y,g(y,o),y))
(6/mean(g(s(1e6,N,1),s(1e6,N,1))==1))^.5
```

Sample output:

```
N=100     -> 3.333333
N=10000   -> 3.137794
N=1000000 -> 3.141709
```

Comment: You can simply use `sample(10^6,N)`. Not only is it shorter, it is also much more efficient.

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't the sample be used with replace=T for a properly uniform random integers.  For example `sample(10,10)` is guaranteed to return all the numbers in 1:10, whereas `sample(10,10,T)` will produce a random selection where numbers can be repeated.

Comment: @MickyT You're absolutely correct, I just realized this a few minutes ago myself. I'm not entirely sure how this plays out mathematically in this instance - as far as I can tell, both methods are roughly equally accurate. I'll edit my post to add this information.

Comment: Both methods are equally accurate when N<<10^6. To handle arbitrarily big N,  you have to sample with replacement, good catch.

Answer (score 7):

### Actually, 19 bytes

```
`6╤;Ju@Ju┤`nkΣß6*/√
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YDbilaQ7SnVASnXilKRgbmvOo8OfNiov4oia&input=MTAw)

Explanation:

```
`6╤;Ju@Ju┤`nkΣß6*/√
`6╤;Ju@Ju┤`n         do this N times:
 6╤;                   two copies of 10**6
    Ju                 random integer in [0, 10**6), increment
      @Ju              another random integer in [0, 10**6), increment
         ┤             1 if coprime else 0
            kΣ       sum the results
              ß      first input again
               6*    multiply by 6
                 /   divide by sum
                  √  square root
```

Comment: i, j aren't allowed to be 0

Comment: @isaacg They aren't. If you'll read the explanation, it says that the random values are selected from [0, 10**6), then incremented.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
1e6Hi3$YrZ}Zd1=Ym6w/X^
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MWU2SGkzJFlyWn1aZDE9WW02dy9YXg&input=MTAwMDA)

```
1e6      % Push 1e6
H        % Push 2
i        % Push input, N
3$Yr     % 2×N matrix of uniformly random integer values between 1 and 1e6
Z}       % Split into its two rows. Gives two 1×N arrays
Zd       % GCD, element-wise. Gives a 1×N array
1=       % Compare each entry with 1. Sets 1 to 0, and other values to 0
Ym       % Mean of the array
6w/      % 6 divided by that
X^       % Square root. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Scala, <s>149</s> 126 bytes

```
val& =BigInt
def f(n: Int)={math.sqrt(6f*n/Seq.fill(n){val i,j=(math.random*99999+1).toInt
if(&(i).gcd(&(j))>1)0 else 1}.sum)}
```

Explanation:

```
val& =BigInt                //define & as an alias to the object BigInt, because it has a gcd method
def f(n:Int)={              //define a method
  math.sqrt(                //take the sqrt of...
    6f * n /                //6 * n (6f is a floating-point literal to prevent integer division)
    Seq.fill(n){            //Build a sequence with n elements, where each element is..
      val i,j=(math.random*99999+1).toInt //take 2 random integers
      if(&(i).gcd(&(j))>1)0 else 1        //put 0 or 1 in the list by calling
                                          //the apply method of & to convert the numbers to
                                          //BigInt and calling its bcd method
    }.sum                   //calculate the sum
  )
}
```

Comment: I <3 Scala! Especially, because it sometimes really needs an explanation.

Comment: @RomanGräf To be honest, the only things I think might be unclear are `6f`, `Seq.fill` and `math.random`.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
@*6cQ/iMcmhO^T6yQ2lN2
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%2a6cQ%2FiMcmhO%5ET6yQ2lN2&input=10000&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                Q          input number
               y           twice that
         m                 map numbers 0 to n-1:
             T                 10
            ^ 6                to the 6th power
           O                   random number from 0 to n-1
          h                    add one
        c        2         split into pairs
      iM                   gcd of each pair
     /            lN       count ones
   cQ                      divide input number by the result
 *6                        multiply by 6
@                   2      square root
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>107</s> <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```
n=>(n*6/(r=_=>Math.random()*1e6+1|0,g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a<2,q=n=>n&&g(r(),r())+q(n-1))(n))**.5
```

The ES6 version is exactly 99 bytes, but the ES7 exponentiation operator `**` saves 5 bytes over `Math.sqrt`.

#### Ungolfed

```
function pi(n) {
  function random() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e6) + 1;
  }
  function gcd(a, b) {
    if (b == 0)
      return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }
  function q(n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 0;
    return (gcd(random(), random()) == 1 ? 1 : 0) + q(n - 1));
  }
  return Math.sqrt(n * 6 / q(n));
}
```

Comment: In the Ungolfed Version `gcd` calls the the function `g`

Comment: `r=_=>` is that code or a drawing?

Comment: ```n=>(n*6/(r=_=>Math.random()*1e6,g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a>-2,q=n=>n&&g(~r(),~r())+q(n-1))(n))**.5``` 1B shorter

Comment: ```n=>(n*6/(q=_=>n--&&q(r=_=>Math.random()*1e6)+g(~r(),~r()))(g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a>-2))**.5```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>82</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```
for(;$i++<$argn;)$s+=2>gmp_gcd(rand(1,1e6),rand(1,1e6));echo(6*$i/$s)**.5;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 10000 | php -R 'for(;$i++<$argn;)$s+=2>gmp_gcd(rand(1,1e6),rand(1,1e6));echo(6*$i/$s)**.5;' 2>/dev/null;echo
```

## Explanation

Does what it says on the tin. Requires PHP_GMP for `gcd`.

## Tweaks

- Saved 3 bytes by using `$argn`

Answer (score 5):

### Racket 92 bytes

```
(λ(N)(sqrt(/(* 6 N)(for/sum((c N))(if(= 1(gcd(random 1 1000000)(random 1 1000000)))1 0)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ (N)
    (sqrt(/ (* 6 N) 
            (for/sum ((c N))
              (if (= 1
                     (gcd (random 1 1000000)
                          (random 1 1000000)))
                  1 0)
              )))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 100)
(f 1000)
(f 100000)
```

Output:

```
2.970442628930023
3.188964020716403
3.144483068444827
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 64 bytes

```perl
sub r{1+~~rand 9x6}$_=sqrt$_*6/grep{2>gcd r,r}1..$_
```

Requires the command line option `-pMntheory=gcd`, counted as 13. Input is taken from stdin.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo 1000 | perl -pMntheory=gcd pi-rock.pl
3.14140431218772
```

Answer (score 4):

## R, 94 bytes

```
N=scan();a=replicate(N,{x=sample(1e6,2);q=1:x[1];max(q[!x[1]%%q&!x[2]%%q])<2});(6*N/sum(a))^.5
```

Relatively slow but still works. Replicate N times a function that takes 2 random numbers (from 1 to 1e6) and checks if their gcd is less than 2 (using an [old gcd function of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48845/6741)).

Comment: If you're not worried about warnings, `1:x` will work.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>118</s> 114 bytes

```
param($n)for(;$k-le$n;$k++){$i,$j=0,1|%{Random -mi 1};while($j){$i,$j=$j,($i%$j)}$o+=!($i-1)}[math]::Sqrt(6*$n/$o)
```

Takes input `$n`, starts a `for` loop until `$k` equals `$n` (implicit `$k=0` upon first entering the loop). Each iteration, get new `Random` numbers `$i` and `$j` (the `-mi`nimum `1` flag ensure we're `>=1` and no maximum flag allows up to `[int]::MaxValue`, which is allowed by the OP since it's larger than `10e6`).

We then go into a [GCD `while` loop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83562/42963). Then, so long as the GCD is `1`, `$o` gets incremented. At the end of the `for` loop, we do a simple `[math]::Sqrt()` call, which gets left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Takes about 15 minutes to run with input `10000` on my ~1 year old Core i5 laptop.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\natural-pi-0-rock.ps1 100
3.11085508419128

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\natural-pi-0-rock.ps1 1000
3.17820863081864

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\natural-pi-0-rock.ps1 10000
3.16756133579975
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>164</s> 151 bytes

```java
n->{int c=n,t=0,x,y;while(c-->0){x=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);y=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);while(y>0)y=x%(x=y);if(x<2)t++;}return Math.sqrt(6f*n/t);}
```

### Explanation

```java
n->{
    int c=n,t=0,x,y;
    while(c-->0){                          // Repeat n times
        x=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);     // Random x
        y=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);     // Random y
        while(y>0)y=x%(x=y);               // GCD
        if(x<2)t++;                        // Coprime?
    }
    return Math.sqrt(6f*n/t);              // Pi
}
```

#### Test Harness

```java
class Main {
    public static interface F{ double f(int n); }
    public static void g(F s){
        System.out.println(s.f(100));
        System.out.println(s.f(1000));
        System.out.println(s.f(10000));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        g(
            n->{int c=n,t=0,y,x;while(c-->0){x=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);y=1+(int)(Math.random()*10e6);while(y>0)y=x%(x=y);if(x<2)t++;}return Math.sqrt(6f*n/t);}
        );
    }
}
```

**Update**

- **-13** [16-10-05] Thanks to [*@TNT*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32515/tnt) and added test harness

Comment: You don't need parentheses around the first `n`, `t+=1` can become `t++`, you can condense your `int` declarations into one line, i.e. `int c=n,t=0,x,y;`, and `!=0` (I think) can become `>0`. That should save 12 bytes overall. That's a neat way of finding the GCD of x and y, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 24 bytes

```
Đ0⇹`⇹ɽɽǤ⁻?ŕ:ŕ⁺;⇹⁻łŕᵮ/6*√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yASDR@07E4D45N6Te48vedS42/7oVKujUx817rIGigL5R5uOTn24dZ2@mdajjln//xsaAAEA)

```
Đ                           implicit input; Đuplicate on stack (N, i) where i is a counter
 0                          push 0 (S)
  ⇹                         swap top two items on stack
   `             ł          do... while top of stack is not 0
    ⇹                       swap top two items on stack
     ɽɽ                     get two ɽandom 32-bit integers
       Ǥ⁻?                  if the ǤCD of the two random integers is >1:
          ŕ                 ŕemove the GCD
           :ŕ⁺              otherwise ŕemove the GCD and increment S
              ;⇹⁻           either way, swap and decrement N
                 ŕ          ŕemove i (which is now 0)
                  ᵮ         cast S to a ᵮloat
                   /        N/S
                    6*√     sqrt(6*N/S); implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Frink,  <s>84</s>  89

```
r[]:=random[10^6]+1
g=n=eval[input[1]]
for a=1to n
g=g-1%gcd[r[],r[]]
println[(6*n/g)^.5]
```

I got lucky: **g=n=...** saves a byte over **g=0 n=...**; and **1%gcd()** gives (0,1) vs (1,0) so I can subtract. 
And unlucky: **n** is preassigned and **a** used because loop variables and their bounds are local and undefined outside the loop.

### Verbose

```
r[] := random[10^6] + 1     // function. Frink parses Unicode superscript!
g = n = eval[input[""]]     // input number, [1] works too
for a = 1 to n              // repeat n times
   g = g - 1%gcd[r[], r[]]  // subtract 1 if gcd(i, j) > 1
println[(6*n/g)^.5]         // ^.5 is shorter than sqrt[x], but no super ".", no ½
```

Comment: That's 90 bytes and 88 chars...?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I didn't count newlines, and while ², ³  are only 1 byte ⁶ is more. I fixed it to 89 bytes with no final newline.

Comment: You have not fixed the verbose code.

Comment: It's not a one-to-one match anyway with spacing, the quotes and numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```perl6
{sqrt 6*$_/(1..10⁶).roll(*).map(*gcd*==1)[^$_].sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLU7D9X11cWFSiYKalEq@vYainZ2jwqHGbpl5Rfk6OhpamXm5igYZWenKKlq2toWZ0nEp8rF5xaW7t/@LESoU0BUMDay4Yy8DA@j8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 109 bytes

```
func G(p,q){return(q?G(q,p%q):p)}{for(;i++<$0;)x+=G(int(1e6*rand()+1),int(1e6*rand()+1))==1;$0=sqrt(6*$0/x)}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcixCoMwEADQX@mQwp0JmFscjKFjvkOsghRi7owoiN@egqtvfP3@K2Xa4vAKkAzjKWPeJAJ/ArBJb8Y24XVOi4Cbte6UdXhoH2COGWhsKunjF1ATmseg9@SU9StLhqZStj7wolLI3v4)

I'm surprised that it runs in a reasonable amount of time for 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
←Đ0⇹`25*⁶⁺Đ1⇹ɾ⇹1⇹ɾǤ1=⇹3Ș+⇹⁻łŕ⇹6*⇹/√
```

Explanation:

```
←Đ                                              Push input onto stack twice
  0                                             Push 0
   ⇹                                            Swap top two elements of stack
    `                      ł                    Repeat until top of stack is 0
     25*⁶⁺Đ1⇹ɾ⇹1⇹ɾ                              Randomly generate two integers in the range [1,10^6]
                  Ǥ1=                           Is their GCD 1?
                     ⇹3Ș                        Reposition top three elements of stack
                        +                       Add the top 2 on the stack
                         ⇹⁻                     Swap the top two and subtract one from the new top of the stack
                            ŕ                   Remove the counter from the stack
                             ⇹                  Swap the top two on the stack
                              6*                Multiply top by 6
                                ⇹               Swap top two
                                 /              Divide the second on the stack by the first
                                  √             Get the square root
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 27 Bytes

```
3 :'%:6*y%+/(1:=?+.?)y#1e6'
```

#### Explanation:

```
3 :'                      '  | Explicit verb definition
                     y#1e6   | List of y copies of 1e6 = 1000000
            (1:=?+.?)        | for each item, generate i and j, and test whether their gcd is 1
          +/                 | Sum the resulting list
      6*y%                   | Divide y by it and multiply by six
    %:                       | Square root
```

Got pretty lucky with a `3.14157` for `N = 10000000`, which took `2.44` seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>23</s> 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
*6/UÆ2ÆÒL³öÃrjÃx)¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=KjYvVcYyxtJMs/bDcmrDeCms&input=MTAwMDA)